# is there a way to get the raw soap call for magento

Tags: magento, soap

I'm trying to make a call to magento via soap. 
I don't have PHP or magento installed, but I want to make a call to the MULTICALL method of api 1.

All examples I see are php and I don't see anyway to reverse engineer the soap that's getting passed.

Is there a tool that I can use to push in the PHP and get the SOAP that gets moved across?

Here's my soap call right now.. It is wrong, but I don't know how.
Again I'm looking for a tool so I don't have to ask this again.

```
 <SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
  xmlns:ns1="urn:Magento" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
    xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:multiCall>
    <sessionId xs:type="type:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2000/XMLSchema-instance">f6bf01f73f6d995ea0a72d13ae3f2a28</sessionId>
    <calls SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:ur-type[0]" xsi:type="ns1:FixedArray">


<item SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[3]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">
                          <item xsi:type="xsd:string">customer.info</item>
                          <item SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:ur-type[2]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">
                          <item xsi:type="ns2:Map">
                            <item>
                                    <key>email</key>
                                <value xsi:type="ns2:Map">
                                   <item>
                                     <key>eq</key>
                                     <value>john.smyth@example.com</value>
                                   </item>
                                </value>
                               </item>
                          </item>
                          </item></item>
</calls>
<options xsi:nil="true"/></ns1:multiCall></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean, but give this a try. http://www.soapui.org/. It helped me a lot so far regarding the SOAP calls.

Comment: I have this block of php code in the magento docs, but since I'm not using php and my app isn't on the same box as magento, I'm sending soap to get info through magento.  Sadly I can't find any examples of the soap that gets (in this instance) the contacts with email = XXX

Comment: an example of the soap docs  http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/customer/customer.list.html totally devoid of even one line of soap :(